# Accessing the Administrator Audit Log via Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Despite fervent searches, I don't believe I have come up with quite the results I am needing. Within the Google Apps for Business Administrator console, under "Reports" there is the "Audit Log." This audit log nearly displays everything I need; however, I am needing the actual name of the file instead of the fileID provided in the report.

The ultimate endgame is to generate, via Google Script, an automated daily report that gives  this same data to a few users daily. Is there any means by which I may access this data? I have been pouring over the APIs, and perhaps I've missed something, but I don't feel that I've found what I needed.

Any thoughts and help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time and considerations.

Comment: Just for your information. The Admin Audit API has been deprecated in favor of the [Admin SDK: Reports API](http://www.linkgard.com/uncategorized/woot-new-reports-api-for-accessing-google-apps-admin-audit-logs.html "Google Admin Logs").

Comment: Thanks so much! That's a huge boon for our organization. Much appreciated information!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible using the [Google Apps Admin Audit API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/admin-audit/). This uses OAuth and that is a bit tricky to setup sometimes. You can see the set up process in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVhsK5jH6u8&feature=player_detailpage#t=1258s) that we did. Except as the example shows, instead of the YouTube APIs enable the Apps Reporting and Audit APIs in the [API Console](http://developers.google.com/console).

I built out a [simple example of this](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzcvt_jzVP78BpE8hDiHlP-gCxSsPqk0F19swlxVjrYxWfF8jAq/exec) that you can see in operation. Access this URL after having been logged in as the domain admin. It will automatically create a Spreadsheet in your Drive with the latest Audit logs exported. This is a web app that is deployed as "Run as user".

[image: Sample audit spreadsheet]

I've open sourced this [Github here](https://github.com/entaq/GoogleAppsScript/blob/master/GoogleAppsAdminAudit.gs). You should substitute in the right OAuth2 Client ID/Secret. The code is pretty rough so you'll want to clean it up. I am selectively logging a few columns but if you look at the API docs, there are other things you can log as well.

Once the OAuth token is set up you can have this run on a trigger as well as long as you refresh the token.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Arun --  Thank you so much! Very informative, helpful, and will be a major pillar in my designs with Google's API from here on out. Much appreciated!