# Checking existing user using google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps-for-education

I am making a Google apps script on a spreadsheet that creates users on a domain submitted from a registeration form powered by Google forms, creating a user was easy using this method `UserManager.createUser(username, firstname, lastname,password);` but the problem that I'm facing is how to check if the user being inserted into the spreadsheet already exists.
I checked over the internet specially at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/ but found nothing helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using a try catch block?  Simple but should facilitate your need.

```
try{
    // Get an existing user
    var user = UserManager.getUser("delete.me");
}catch(e){
    // If user does not exist // i.e. error // create the user
    var newUser = UserManager.createUser('delete.me', 'Delete', 'Me', 'testing123');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct API for it from Apps Script, but you can use the [User Provisioning](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/) 
 using OAuth 2 and UrlFetchApp. You can see some [sample integration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15124712/662551) with the [Audit API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/admin-audit/)

Comment: sorry but can you explain more? how can i use the audit api in such thing?

Comment: You would replace the Audit API with the Provisioning API. They are very similar APIs. THe post I pointed out should give you the structure and approach you need to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 versions of a script that gets all users in my domain, the second one uses the API that Arun mentioned and returns an XML document viewable in the logger (for this test version) that you could parse in a suitable way.

The other one (the first actually) uses `UserManager` service and shows the results in a spreadsheet. From there (using the array) it would be easy to check if a user already has an account.

here is the code :

```
function findUsers(s) {     
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  sheet.getDataRange().clear()
  var users = UserManager.getAllUsers();
  var r = new Array();
//
  for( var i = 0 ; i < users.length ; i++ ){
    var Umail = users[i].getEmail(); 
    var UnomF = users[i].getFamilyName()
    var UnomP = users[i].getGivenName()

      if(users[i].getAgreedToTerms()){var Udejaconnect = 'oui'}else{var Udejaconnect = 'jamais'}
//
     r.push([UnomF,UnomP,Umail,Udejaconnect]);
  }   
  r.sort(function(x,y){
  var xp = x[0].toLowerCase();
  var yp = y[0].toLowerCase();
  Logger.log(xp+'   '+yp)
  return xp == yp ? 0 : xp < yp ? -1 : 1;//  sort on name ascending
}
)
  var header = ['Nom de famille','Prénom','Email','Déjà Connecté?']
    sheet.getRange(1,1,1,r[0].length).setValues([header]).setFontWeight('bold')
    .setBackground('silver').setBorder(true,true,true,true,true,true);
    sheet.getRange(2,1,r.length,r[0].length).setValues(r);
}

// new version provisioning API
//
function getUserData() {
  var base = "https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/";
  var fetchArgs = googleOAuth_("provisioning", base);
  var url = base + "domain.name" + "/user/2.0"; 

  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,fetchArgs).getContentText()
  var xml = Xml.parse(result);
  Logger.log(result)
  var users = xml.feed.entry;

  var r = [['Login', 'Nom complet', "Droits d'admin.", 'Quota Emails', 'Compte suspendu']];
  for( var i in users ) 
            r.push([users[i].login.userName,
            users[i].name.givenName+' '+users[i].name.familyName,
            users[i].login.admin,
            users[i].quota.limit,
            users[i].login.suspended]);
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  s.clearContents();
  s.getRange(1, 1, r.length, r[0].length).setValues(r);

}


function googleOAuth_(name,scope) {
  var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(name);
  oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
  oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
  oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey("anonymous");
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret("anonymous");
  return {oAuthServiceName:name, oAuthUseToken:"always"};
}
```

Comment: thank you so much i read your answer and understood what you meant with this approach, except that the other answer is straight to what i need nothing more, thanks again.