# How can you generate a report for newly created groups/DLs on a weekly basis?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I am an admin for a Google Apps for Business domain and we want to be able to run a report to tell us what groups have been created in the last week. There is no such "Date Created" column for the groups. The best I have been able to do so far is run a list of the groups on a weekly basis but I want to be able to automate comparing that to the list from the week before.

Answer (score 1):

You might as well store the list you have goten in a 'permanent storage' - a spreadsheet, ScriptDB or script Properties - and proceed to a comparison every week to see if something has been added (or removed)... This is maybe less straightforward and elegant but might be simpler to get working.

The weekly triggered function could do this :

- get the list of names
- sort it
- write the sorted list to spreadsheet
- retrieve the sorted list from last week by reading the preceding row in spreadsheet
- compare both sorted lists at array level
- and send yourself a mail with the difference.(eventually write the log to the spreadsheet)

Answer (score 0):

This is certainly possible but requires a bit of coding.

You'll have to use the [Audit API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/admin-audit/using) for this. See [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15097599/accessing-the-administrator-audit-log-via-google-script/15124712#15124712) for some starter code on how to make basic calls to the API. The one tricky part is to set up OAuth 2 but its very possible after that.

Once you have the setup working you can then add additional `startTime` and `endTime` parameters to define your week interval along with the [CREATE_GROUP](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/admin-audit/event_names#create-group) event filter in the URL.